Добавление товаров в корзину из файла woocommerce
В интернет-магазине работающем на Wordpress с плагином WooCommerce нужно реализовать добавление товаров в корзину с помощью файла. Пользователь буквально загружает таблицу с нужными позициями и артикулами, а сайт автоматически предлагает добавить все эти позиции в корзину. Более того, иногда бывает что по каким либо причинам завод выпускает старый товар под новым артикулом (старые и новые известны) по возможно нужно реализовать автоматическое изменение старых артикулов на новые. Есть ли плагин, который закроет хотя бы первый вопрос?

"Пользователь" - это покупатель или менеджер ИМ? Вопрос по артикулам - это второй вопрос и задавать его нужно отдельно.

"Пользователь" - это покупатель. А второй вопрос напрямую относится к первому. Я имел в виду, что бы артикулы заменялись как раз при добавлении через файл.

Второй вопрос - это другой вопрос, согласно правилам SO. Но это звучит как бред - покупатель будет менять артикулы.. Впрочем, и первая задача, мягко говоря, странная. Очень похоже на ошибку XY. Покупатель должен получить определённый формат файла, не ошибиться в заполнении и ещё 100500 нюансов. Это вместо того чтобы просто выбрать всё тоже самое на сайте, без всего этого геммороя.

Интернет-магазин специализируется на обслуживании мини-тэц. Как вы думаете случайный покупатель зайдёт на сайт? И если вы работаете в данной среде вам будет удобно выбирать порядка 70 позиций в ручную, когда у вас есть готовый список спецификаций?

При правильном построении сайта даже тыщи позиций будет выбирать легче, чем проходить квест с файлами. При этом надёжней на два порядка.
